# how to insert value unicode from asp.net to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, asp.net, mysql-workbench

I use procedure to insert data from asp.net to mysql workbench. It have problem about value of data  when insert. value of data use unicode UFT8. But when i insert into table, it corrupted font. **I don't know how to fix font when insert data.**

Create Table MYSQL Workbench 6.2:

```
CREATE TABLE Story(
    ID_Story int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(200) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    DateTimeNew datetime ,
    Image varchar(300) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    Description LONGTEXT NULL,
    Rate float NULL,
    Author varchar(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    Readed int NULL,
    Cate tinyint default '0', 
    tinhtrang nvarchar(20) default 'Đang ra'
) CHARSET=utf8;
```

Code Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Story(p_Name varchar(200)  CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
    ,p_Image varchar(300)  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    ,p_Description longtext
    ,p_Rate double
    ,p_Author varchar(40)  CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
    ,p_Cate tinyint unsigned
    ,p_return varchar(100)  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'  ) 
begin
    set p_Name = (select REPLACE(p_Name,'<h2>',''));
    set p_Name = (select REPLACE(p_Name,'</h2>',''));
    if(select COUNT(ID_Story) from Story where Name = p_Name) = 0
    then
        insert into Story(Name,Image,Description,Rate,Author,Cate) values  
        (p_Name,p_Image,p_Description,p_Rate,p_Author,p_Cate);
        set p_return = Concat(N'0|Tạo mới|' ,  last_insert_id());
    else 
        set p_return = Concat(N'1|Đa tồn tại |' , (select  ID_Story from Story where Name = p_Name limit 1));
    END IF;
END
```

Code Insert MySQL of Asp.net

```
 String connectionstring = @"Data Source=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;;database=doctruyen;";
            using (MySqlConnection cns = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update_Story", cns);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Name","13132àáạảã");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Image", "1312àáạảã");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Description", "1312àáạảã");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Rate", "12");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Author", "1312àáạảã");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Cate", "1");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("p_return", MySqlDbType.Text).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cns.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write("goi" +cmd.Parameters["p_return"].Value.ToString());
                cns.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                Response.Write("con");
            }
```

Result insert (**it has corrupted font in the insert**):

```
1   13132àá??ã      13132àá??ã  1312àá??ã   12  1312àá??ã       1   Đang ra
```